# Initialize variable using another variable's initialized value in Swift

Tags: swift

So what I wanna do is:

```
let margin: CGFloat = 10
let width: CGFloat = 100 - margin
// also used self.margin
```

but here's the error I'm getting:

```
Instance member 'margin' cannot be used on type 'HistoryViewController'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let margin: CGFloat = 10
var width: CGFloat { return 100 - self.margin }
```

Or

```
lazy var width: CGFloat = 100 - self.margin
```

This is because at instance variable initialization time, the instance doesn't exist yet. Using lazy initialization or a computed property will fix this.

Comment: Thanks both solutions worked. I chose the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var margin: CGFloat {
  return 10.0
}
var width: CGFloat {
  return 100 - margin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

first declare the class level variables like this:

```
let margin: CGFloat = 10
var width = CGFloat()
```

Then give your width a value inside a function, say `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        width = 100 - margin
    }
```

Thank You! 
Happy Coding